# TailwindCSS grid row above

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm struggling to place a div above a specific row and make it span "n" rows without pushing down other rows, I want to draw it above them.

The problem right now is that, when I place this div (the green one in the screenshot) it pushes down the rows already drawn.

[image]

This is the code that draws the image on the picture:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-[6rem_auto] grid-rows-[repeat(10,minmax(2rem,min-content))] gap-0 p-2">
            <div class="border p-2 col-start-1 row-span-1 row-start-1">Hour</div>
            <div class="border p-2 col-start-2 row-span-1 row-start-1">Prof1</div>
            <div class="border p-2 col-start-3 row-span-1 row-start-1">Prof2</div>

            <!-- Hours -->
            <div class="border mt-1 p-1 col-start-1 row-span-3 row-start-2 flex flex-row">
                <div class="h-full w-full text-xl flex items-center justify-center">07:00</div>
                <div class="h-full flex flex-col justify-end">
                    <div class="text-xs w-8 h-full flex items-center justify-end">15<hr class="w-2 h-0.5 bg-gray-300 ml-1"></div>
                    <div class="text-xs w-8 h-full flex items-center justify-end">30<hr class="w-2 h-0.5 bg-gray-300 ml-1"></div>
                    <div class="text-xs w-8 h-full flex items-center justify-end">45<hr class="w-2 h-0.5 bg-gray-300 ml-1"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="border p-1 col-start-1 row-span-3 row-start-5 flex flex-row">
                <div class="h-full w-full text-xl flex items-center justify-center">08:00</div>
                <div class="h-full flex flex-col">
                    <div class="text-xs w-8 h-full flex items-center justify-end">15<hr class="w-2 h-0.5 bg-gray-300 ml-1"></div>
                    <div class="text-xs w-8 h-full flex items-center justify-end">30<hr class="w-2 h-0.5 bg-gray-300 ml-1"></div>
                    <div class="text-xs w-8 h-full flex items-center justify-end">45<hr class="w-2 h-0.5 bg-gray-300 ml-1"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="border p-1 col-start-1 row-span-3 row-start-8 flex flex-row">
                <div class="h-full w-full text-xl flex items-center justify-center">09:00</div>
                <div class="h-full flex flex-col">
                    <div class="text-xs w-8 h-full flex items-center justify-end">15<hr class="w-2 h-0.5 bg-gray-300 ml-1"></div>
                    <div class="text-xs w-8 h-full flex items-center justify-end">30<hr class="w-2 h-0.5 bg-gray-300 ml-1"></div>
                    <div class="text-xs w-8 h-full flex items-center justify-end">45<hr class="w-2 h-0.5 bg-gray-300 ml-1"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Prof 1 -->
            <div class="mt-1 bg-gray-100 col-start-2 row-start-2 p-2 border-dotted border-b border-gray-400"></div>
            <div class="bg-gray-100 col-start-2 row-start-3 p-2 border-dotted border-b border-gray-400"></div>
            <div class="bg-red-100 col-start-2 row-start-4 p-2 border-dotted border-b border-gray-400"></div>
            <div class="bg-red-100 col-start-2 row-start-5 p-2 border-dotted border-b border-gray-400"></div>
            <div class="bg-red-100 col-start-2 row-start-6 p-2 border-dotted border-b border-gray-400"></div>
            <div class="bg-red-100 col-start-2 row-start-7 p-2 border-dotted border-b border-gray-400"></div>
            <div class="bg-red-100 col-start-2 row-start-8 p-2 border-dotted border-b border-gray-400"></div>
            <div class="bg-gray-100 col-start-2 row-start-9 p-2 border-dotted border-b border-gray-400"></div>
            <div class="bg-gray-100 col-start-2 row-start-10 p-2 border-dotted border-b border-gray-400"></div>

            <!-- This is the div that pushes down previously drawn rows -->
            <div class="bg-green-400 col-start-2 w-1/3 row-start-7 row-span-3 m-1 p-2 rounded-md border-dotted border-b border-gray-400"></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-row), `row-start-*` classes only go up to `7` by default.

You could use arbitrary value for `8` and above:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div class="grid grid-cols-[6rem_auto] grid-rows-[repeat(10,minmax(2rem,min-content))] gap-0 p-2">
  <div class="border p-2 col-start-1 row-span-1 row-start-1">Hour</div>
  <div class="border p-2 col-start-2 row-span-1 row-start-1">Prof1</div>
  <div class="border p-2 col-start-3 row-span-1 row-start-1">Prof2</div>

  <!-- Hours -->
  <div class="border mt-1 p-1 col-start-1 row-span-3 row-start-2 flex flex-row">
    <div class="h-full w-full text-xl flex items-center justify-center">07:00</div>
    <div class="h-full flex flex-col justify-end">
      <div class="text-xs w-8 h-full flex items-center justify-end">15
        <hr class="w-2 h-0.5 bg-gray-300 ml-1">
      </div>
      <div class="text-xs w-8 h-full flex items-center justify-end">30
        <hr class="w-2 h-0.5 bg-gray-300 ml-1">
      </div>
      <div class="text-xs w-8 h-full flex items-center justify-end">45
        <hr class="w-2 h-0.5 bg-gray-300 ml-1">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="border p-1 col-start-1 row-span-3 row-start-5 flex flex-row">
    <div class="h-full w-full text-xl flex items-center justify-center">08:00</div>
    <div class="h-full flex flex-col">
      <div class="text-xs w-8 h-full flex items-center justify-end">15
        <hr class="w-2 h-0.5 bg-gray-300 ml-1">
      </div>
      <div class="text-xs w-8 h-full flex items-center justify-end">30
        <hr class="w-2 h-0.5 bg-gray-300 ml-1">
      </div>
      <div class="text-xs w-8 h-full flex items-center justify-end">45
        <hr class="w-2 h-0.5 bg-gray-300 ml-1">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="border p-1 col-start-1 row-span-3 row-start-8 flex flex-row">
    <div class="h-full w-full text-xl flex items-center justify-center">09:00</div>
    <div class="h-full flex flex-col">
      <div class="text-xs w-8 h-full flex items-center justify-end">15
        <hr class="w-2 h-0.5 bg-gray-300 ml-1">
      </div>
      <div class="text-xs w-8 h-full flex items-center justify-end">30
        <hr class="w-2 h-0.5 bg-gray-300 ml-1">
      </div>
      <div class="text-xs w-8 h-full flex items-center justify-end">45
        <hr class="w-2 h-0.5 bg-gray-300 ml-1">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Prof 1 -->
  <div class="mt-1 bg-gray-100 col-start-2 row-start-2 p-2 border-dotted border-b border-gray-400"></div>
  <div class="bg-gray-100 col-start-2 row-start-3 p-2 border-dotted border-b border-gray-400"></div>
  <div class="bg-red-100 col-start-2 row-start-4 p-2 border-dotted border-b border-gray-400"></div>
  <div class="bg-red-100 col-start-2 row-start-5 p-2 border-dotted border-b border-gray-400"></div>
  <div class="bg-red-100 col-start-2 row-start-6 p-2 border-dotted border-b border-gray-400"></div>
  <div class="bg-red-100 col-start-2 row-start-7 p-2 border-dotted border-b border-gray-400"></div>
  <div class="bg-red-100 col-start-2 row-start-[8] p-2 border-dotted border-b border-gray-400"></div>
  <div class="bg-gray-100 col-start-2 row-start-[9] p-2 border-dotted border-b border-gray-400"></div>
  <div class="bg-gray-100 col-start-2 row-start-[10] p-2 border-dotted border-b border-gray-400"></div>

  <!-- This is the div that pushes down previously drawn rows -->
  <div class="bg-green-400 col-start-2 w-1/3 row-start-7 row-span-3 m-1 p-2 rounded-md border-dotted border-b border-gray-400"></div>
</div>
```

Or add the `8`+ values in the Tailwind configuration:

```js
tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      gridRowStart: {
        8: '8',
        9: '9',
        10: '10',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div class="grid grid-cols-[6rem_auto] grid-rows-[repeat(10,minmax(2rem,min-content))] gap-0 p-2">
  <div class="border p-2 col-start-1 row-span-1 row-start-1">Hour</div>
  <div class="border p-2 col-start-2 row-span-1 row-start-1">Prof1</div>
  <div class="border p-2 col-start-3 row-span-1 row-start-1">Prof2</div>

  <!-- Hours -->
  <div class="border mt-1 p-1 col-start-1 row-span-3 row-start-2 flex flex-row">
    <div class="h-full w-full text-xl flex items-center justify-center">07:00</div>
    <div class="h-full flex flex-col justify-end">
      <div class="text-xs w-8 h-full flex items-center justify-end">15
        <hr class="w-2 h-0.5 bg-gray-300 ml-1">
      </div>
      <div class="text-xs w-8 h-full flex items-center justify-end">30
        <hr class="w-2 h-0.5 bg-gray-300 ml-1">
      </div>
      <div class="text-xs w-8 h-full flex items-center justify-end">45
        <hr class="w-2 h-0.5 bg-gray-300 ml-1">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="border p-1 col-start-1 row-span-3 row-start-5 flex flex-row">
    <div class="h-full w-full text-xl flex items-center justify-center">08:00</div>
    <div class="h-full flex flex-col">
      <div class="text-xs w-8 h-full flex items-center justify-end">15
        <hr class="w-2 h-0.5 bg-gray-300 ml-1">
      </div>
      <div class="text-xs w-8 h-full flex items-center justify-end">30
        <hr class="w-2 h-0.5 bg-gray-300 ml-1">
      </div>
      <div class="text-xs w-8 h-full flex items-center justify-end">45
        <hr class="w-2 h-0.5 bg-gray-300 ml-1">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="border p-1 col-start-1 row-span-3 row-start-8 flex flex-row">
    <div class="h-full w-full text-xl flex items-center justify-center">09:00</div>
    <div class="h-full flex flex-col">
      <div class="text-xs w-8 h-full flex items-center justify-end">15
        <hr class="w-2 h-0.5 bg-gray-300 ml-1">
      </div>
      <div class="text-xs w-8 h-full flex items-center justify-end">30
        <hr class="w-2 h-0.5 bg-gray-300 ml-1">
      </div>
      <div class="text-xs w-8 h-full flex items-center justify-end">45
        <hr class="w-2 h-0.5 bg-gray-300 ml-1">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Prof 1 -->
  <div class="mt-1 bg-gray-100 col-start-2 row-start-2 p-2 border-dotted border-b border-gray-400"></div>
  <div class="bg-gray-100 col-start-2 row-start-3 p-2 border-dotted border-b border-gray-400"></div>
  <div class="bg-red-100 col-start-2 row-start-4 p-2 border-dotted border-b border-gray-400"></div>
  <div class="bg-red-100 col-start-2 row-start-5 p-2 border-dotted border-b border-gray-400"></div>
  <div class="bg-red-100 col-start-2 row-start-6 p-2 border-dotted border-b border-gray-400"></div>
  <div class="bg-red-100 col-start-2 row-start-7 p-2 border-dotted border-b border-gray-400"></div>
  <div class="bg-red-100 col-start-2 row-start-8 p-2 border-dotted border-b border-gray-400"></div>
  <div class="bg-gray-100 col-start-2 row-start-9 p-2 border-dotted border-b border-gray-400"></div>
  <div class="bg-gray-100 col-start-2 row-start-10 p-2 border-dotted border-b border-gray-400"></div>

  <!-- This is the div that pushes down previously drawn rows -->
  <div class="bg-green-400 col-start-2 w-1/3 row-start-7 row-span-3 m-1 p-2 rounded-md border-dotted border-b border-gray-400"></div>
</div>
```